# Problem showing a country with non contiguous border

Tags: geojson, line, delimiter

I am generating maps using Google Static API.

Due to browser size restrictions, I am doing a **polyline encoding**, using an online polyline encoder. The encoder takes long,lat with a line break.

Most maps come out OK. But wherever there are countries which have non contiguous areas, I don't get the map right. I figured that it has something to do with start/end point. In a GeoJSON, I notice that it is handled using an extra SQUARE BRACKET. Could it be that I am missing a similar delimiter in my long,lat data. I do not know how to handle this. I get an annoying extra line connecting the two separate regions.

How do I get rid of this line?

[image: My Map]

[image: Correct Map]

Comment: Would think you'd want a MultiPolygon, see example in the GeoJSON specification ~ https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#appendix-A